Using SignalR on Azure App Service running Linux
I'm hosting my ASP.NET Core app - targeting .NET 8 - on Azure App Service running on Linux with a Basic (B1) hosting plan. My app uses SignalR as well.
I don't see a SignalR option under Settings > Configuration. I read somewhere that on Linux, WebSockets are always on but my .NET MAUI app is unable to establish a SignalR connection with my ASP.NET Core app.
Any ideas/suggestions?

Please share more details about the issue.

You don't have a default integration with SignalR on linux. You must create an Azure SignalR resource.  You have here more explanations on how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core

@DA I’m a bit confused. My ASP.NET Core app provides the SignalR hubs. As far as I know, Azure SignalR service is primarily for managing connections in a scalable way which I don’t need at this stage. Are you saying the Linux based web server doesn’t provide web sockets?


Change transport from WebSockets to another and test again. This rules out any components you are not aware of that do not support WebSockets. 2. Switch to Azure SignalR which is a more robust option.


And here’s the documentation that indicates WebSockets setting on Linux is always on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#web-sockets

The following document makes publishing an ASP.NET Core SignalR app to Azure App Service on Linux clear.
I want to clarify three important points here:

All Azure App Service hosting plans on Linux, including the free tier support ASP.NET Core SignalR and using Azure SignalR service is NOT required
WebSockets on Azure App Service on Linux seem to be ON by default which may explain why the WebSockets settings doesn't appear under Settings > Configuration if the hosting plan is using Linux as the operating system
One requirement seems to be turning ON the "Session Affinity" setting. In my case it was OFF and I had to turn it ON manually. This may be its default setting

Here's the Microsoft documentation that provides detailed information on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-the-app-in-azure-app-service
Here's another useful document that provides FAQ for App Service on Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux
One final point: a few suggested using Azure SignalR service here. The Azure SignalR service is definitely a good choice when needed but one needs to assess that need carefully. From everything I've read so far, the primary benefits of using Azure SignalR service are scalability and management of connections. With that said even the "Basic" hosting plan on Linux seems to support ~50K web sockets per instance. Here's the link to the documentation that provides this info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits
It may not be necessary to jump to Azure SignalR service unless the requirements of the app warrant it.
